# No errors inside apache error.log when perl script fail

Tags: apache, logging, error-handling, mod-perl

I'm trying to debug why my index.pl file generate an error, but inside the error log of apache there is nothing logged. How can I set properly my environment to see what's happened?
I don't think is a problem with file permissions.

This is my configuration for the vhost with apache2:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test_perl
    DocumentRoot /var/www/test
    ErrorLog /var/www/test/error_test.log
    LogLevel debug

   <Directory />
       AllowOverride All
       Options All -Indexes +ExecCGI
       AddHandler perl-script .pl
       PerlHandler ModPerl::Registry
       PerlSendHeader On
   </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And this is the HTTP response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Sun, 26 Aug 2012 18:08:47 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)
Content-Type: text/x-perl
```

without body.

But when I run the file using the command line I can see the errors.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Although you probably don't want the body to be empty, it appears there is no error condition occurring with your HTTP response. You could look to see what's different between command-line invocation and HTTP invocation. One tool for that purpose is Apache's [printenv example CGI script](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/docs/cgi-examples/printenv?revision=1335882&view=markup).

Answer (score 0):

By default all `warn` and `STDERR` output goes to the main Apache error log instead of the `ErrorLog` specified in the vhost configuration.

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/525627/on-apache2-mod-perl2-stderr-output-doesnt-go-to-logfile-nominated-by-errorlog/918627#918627